# nodejs - mock YQL request using nock

Tags: node.js, mocking, yql

I'm trying to write up some unit tests for a script but I can't seem to get [YQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yql) and [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) working together. Using `nock` I can mock `http` requests no problem, as the below example show's, but the test for `yql` is failing, `yql` is always producing no results, no matter what I use (and i've tried `xpath` in the query as well).

```
var http = require('http'),
    nock = require('nock'),
    yql = require('yql')

/**
 * Mock request & test with http
 */
var api = nock("http://example.tld")
    .get("/foobar/")
    .reply(200, "<html><body><table><tr><td class=\"tablebody\"><a href=\"#\">link</a></td></tr></table></body></html>")

http.get("http://example.tld/foobar/", function(resp){
    var str = "";

    resp.on("data", function(data){ str+=data})
    resp.on("end", function(){
        console.log("Got Result: ", str)
    })
})


/**
 * Mock request and test with YQL
 */
var api = nock("http://example.tld")
    .get("/foobar/")
    .reply(200, "<html><body><table><tr><td class=\"tablebody\"><a href=\"#\">link</a></td></tr></table></body></html>")

var query = new yql('select * from html where url="http://example.tld/foobar/"')
query.exec(function(err, results){

    console.log(results)
})
```

I'm wondering is this an headers issue, but anything I've tried has also produced no results with `yql`.
 - any and all help much appreciated, daithi

Answer (score 0):

Seems `nock` double escapes the url, which is a problem for me as the url contains an escaped url.

In the end I used [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire#examples) which allowed me to stub `yql.exec`. So my unit test for `yql` now looks like:

```
var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('expectedResult.json', 'utf8'))
    yqlStub = function(query){
        return {
            exec: function(fn){
                fn(null, json)
            }
        }
    },
    myModule = proxyrequire('lib/myModule.js', {'yql', yqlStub})

myModule.run("http://example.tld", function(err, result){
    //test result here
})
```